# Finding limit of sequence in R related to min/max

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_{n}\}$, $\{b_{n}\}$ be sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\{c_{n}\} = \min(a_{n},b_{n})$, $\{d_{n}\} = \max(a_{n},b_{n})$.

We know $\{b_{n}\}$ converges and $\lim_{n \to \infty} |c_{n}| = \lim_{n \to \infty} d_{n} = 100$.

Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n}| = 100$?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Are you looking for hints or a full solution?

Comment: I know the solution (the answer is actually "yes"). I just want to share this interesting problem with beginners in analysis.